# How to use Overlay for osmdroid with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, overlay, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I've managed to run OSM and GMS in one app using fragments. And I know how to use markers (Overlay) in app using activities. I have a problem using Overlay for OSM in app with fragments, because to use OSM i need to create static class for it and ItemizedOverlay requires using getApplicationContext() method for ResourceProxy that can't be referenced from static context.

This is a working OSM class using fragments:

```
    public static class MapOSM extends Fragment{               // Klasa odpowiedzialna za fragment z mapą OSM

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_osm, container, false);

        osmRl = (MapView) rl.findViewById(R.id.mapOsm2);
        osmRl.getTileProvider().setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

        return rl;
    }
}
```

And this i need to use to get Overlay working:

```
    ResourceProxy resourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
    myItemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(marker, resourceProxy);
    map.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);
```

Thanks for any answer :)

Comment: have you tried to use `ResourceProxy resourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getActivity().getApplicationContext());` inside the fragment?

Comment: Yea, it is working now, I'm still learning java:) Thank You for helping me out:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to "k3b", I'm posting my working OSM class using fragments, with 2 added markers.

```
public static class MapOSM extends Fragment{               // Klasa odpowiedzialna za fragment z mapą OSM

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_osm, container, false);

        osmRl = (MapView) ll.findViewById(R.id.mapOsm2);
        osmRl.getTileProvider().setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

        osmRl.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        osmRl.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        //Overlay
        MyItemizedOverlay myItemizedOverlay = null;

        IMapController mapController = osmRl.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(9);
        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(54.792140, 18.402407);
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);

        /// Markery na mapie
        Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
        assert marker != null;
        int markerWidth = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
        marker.setBounds(0, markerHeight, markerWidth, 0);

        ResourceProxy resourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        myItemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(marker, resourceProxy);
        osmRl.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);

        GeoPoint myPoint1 = new GeoPoint(54.792140, 18.402407);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint1, "myPoint1", "myPoint1");
        GeoPoint myPoint2 = new GeoPoint(54.752, 18.422);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint2, "myPoint2", "myPoint2");

        return ll;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone:)